# Remove sequential characters from the start of a string

Tags: python, regex

What's the best was to strip out the alphabetical letters that are sometimes at the start of Wikipedia references?

e.g. From

> a b c d Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith (DVD). 20th Century Fox. 2005.

to

> Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith (DVD). 20th Century Fox. 2005.

I've hacked together a solution that works, but seems clunky. My version uses a regular expression in the form '^(?:a (?:b (?:c )?)?)?'. What's a proper, fast way to do it?

```
a = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
reg = "^%s%s" % ( "".join(["(?:%s " %b for b in a]), ")?"*len(a) )
re.sub(reg, "", "a b c d Wikipedia Reference")
```

Comment: what about `a boy and his dog`?

Comment: Good point. Getting around this would mean parsing the HTML rather than plain text, I suppose. Although, indefinite articles can always be sacrificed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably just do something like this:

```
title = re.sub(r'^([a-z]\s)*', '', 'a b c d Wikipedia Reference')
```

which does the same as what you've got there.  Like @joran-beasley points out, however, you might need something cleverer for the complicated cases.

Comment: Nice. Though we don't keep the order, (e.g. it would match "a c d "), I can't imagine a case where that would be a problem, while the readability is much better. I benchmarked this option after posting the question (though with a + rather than *) and found it 2.3x as fast.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a character class in your regular expression, i.e.:

```
re.sub('^([a-z] )*', '', ...)
```

That should remove any number of leading occurrences of a single alphabetic character followed by a single space.

Answer (score 1):

If you are copying and pasting webpage text rather than processing html, some problems as mentioned in the question are inevitable.  But processing html (the relevant line as shown below) using [htmllib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmllib.html), you can remove items like `<sup><i><b>c</b></i></sup>` (which contributes the **c**) as units.  [*Edit:* I now see htmllib is deprecated; I don't know the proper replacement but believe it is [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html#module-HTMLParser).]

The displayed line is somewhat like

> ^ <sup>***a***</sup> <sup>***b***</sup> <sup>***c***</sup> <sup>***d***</sup> <sup>***e***</sup> *Star Wars: Episode III Revenge of the Sith* DVD commentary featuring George Lucas, Rick McCallum, Rob Coleman, John Knoll and Roger Guyett, [2005]

and the html source of the line is

`<li id="cite_note-DVDcom-13"><span class="mw-cite-backlink">^ <a href="#cite_ref-DVDcom_13-0"><sup><i><b>a</b></i></sup></a> <a href="#cite_ref-DVDcom_13-1"><sup><i><b>b</b></i></sup></a> <a href="#cite_ref-DVDcom_13-2"><sup><i><b>c</b></i></sup></a> <a href="#cite_ref-DVDcom_13-3"><sup><i><b>d</b></i></sup></a> <a href="#cite_ref-DVDcom_13-4"><sup><i><b>e</b></i></sup></a></span> <span class="reference-text"><i>Star Wars: Episode III Revenge of the Sith</i> DVD commentary featuring George Lucas, Rick McCallum, Rob Coleman, John Knoll and Roger Guyett, [2005]</span></li>`

Comment: parsing the source is a better idea, certainly, and I'd use BeautifulSoup and/or lxml to do this.  there are also specific mediawiki parsers available which might be the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Do they always follow that pattern where there are four extra letters with spaces between in front of the title? If so, you could do this:

```
s = "a b c d Star Wars Episode III: Revenge of the Sith (DVD). 20th Century Fox. 2005."
if all([len(x) == 1 and x.isalpha() for x in s.split()[0:4]]):
    print s[8:]
```